# Appengine Channel attempts to connect to IP 0.0.0.0

Tags: google-app-engine, channel

I am debugging a problem with Channel API use which occurs locally (compiled) and deployed depending on my GWT Logging configuration when I GWT compile it.

NOTE: I am aware of the problem in GAE 1.7.2 with Channels and add in the _ah_DevSocketFilter in my web.xml when running local, to get around it.

Starting up my page locally (127.0.0.1:8888) I get the following output in Chrome's console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/channel/dev?command=connect&channel=channel-vzwzro-1350552986426-ALL:ALL 500 (ApplicationError: 2: Received exception executing http method POST against URL http://0.0.0.0:8888/_ah/channel/connected/: Permission denied: Not allowed to issue a socket connect: permission denied.)
```

Does anyone know where it's getting that 0.0.0.0 IP address from, and why?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Did you find out what was wrong?